# Emmet abbreviations- text inside an element tag

Tags: emmet

Is there a way to encode text inside an element in Emmet. For example if I want to create a  would this be possible with emmet abbreviations?

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly. Can you give an example of what you would like to do? E.g.  h1{My Text} will add the text inside h1 element tag like this <h1>My Text</h1>

Comment: Please accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 48):

You can use curly braces to add text to an element.

For example `article{This is some text inside an article}` expands to `<article>This is some text inside an article</article>`

Answer (score 19):

.item{My $ text}*3

```
<div class="item">My 1 text</div>
<div class="item">My 2 text</div>
<div class="item">My 3 text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
The first example starts from 1 and the second example starts from 6
```

```html
ul>li.item$*5
<ul>
    <li class="item1"></li>
    <li class="item2"></li>
    <li class="item3"></li>
    <li class="item4"></li>
    <li class="item5"></li>
</ul>

ul>li.item$@6*5

<ul>
    <li class="item6"></li>
    <li class="item7"></li>
    <li class="item8"></li>
    <li class="item9"></li>
    <li class="item10"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert lorem ipsum to tags, e.g.

li.text-warning>lorem10

Result:

```html
<li class="text-warning">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, molestias.</li>
```

Hope that workaround is ok.